# Add Up <TD> Values in Row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of `<td>`s in a row and I know the row number.

The `<td>`s have ids like the following:

TaskHours_0__SaturdayHours
TaskHours_0__SundayHours
TaskHours_0__MondayHours
TaskHours_0__TuesdayHours
TaskHours_0__WednesdayHours
TaskHours_0__ThursdayHours
TaskHours_0__FridayHours

where the 0 increments based on the row number.

I am attempting to write something to add up all the values of each TD when I supply it the row number.

I was hoping to write something like this:

```
function rowtotal(rownumber){
    var total = 0;
    total = Number($("#TaskHours_0__SaturdayHours").html())
        + Number($("#TaskHours_0__SundayHours").html())
        + Number($("#TaskHours_0__MondayHours").html())
        + Number($("##TaskHours_0__TuesdayHours").html())
        + Number($("#TaskHours_0__WednesdayHours").html())
        + Number($("#TaskHours_0__ThursdayHours").html())
        + Number($("#TaskHours_0__FridayHours").html())
    return total;
}
```

But I am unable to work out how to substitute the "0" with the parameter "rownumber"

Is there a way to replace the 0 please?

Comment: `Number($("#TaskHours_"+rownumber+"__SaturdayHours")` Isn't it this simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `Array` to store the name of the week days in order to reduce duplicate code (DRY coding) and string `concatenation` to create the `jQuery` selector.

A cleaner version of your code:

```
var weekDays = ['Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 
                'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];

function rowtotal(rowNumber){
    var total = 0;

    weekDays.forEach(function(day) {
      total += Number($('#TaskHours_' + rowNumber + '__' + day + 'Hours').html());
    });

    return total;
}
```

Also, you can also convert a `string` to a `number` by prefixing it with the `+` sign, so instead of this
`Number($('#TaskHours_' + rowNumber + '__' + day + 'Hours').html())`
You can write this:
`+$('#TaskHours_' + rowNumber + '__' + day + 'Hours').html()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `+` to concatenate it in between.:

```
total = Number($("#TaskHours_"+rownumber+"__SaturdayHours").html())
```

same for other tds.